# Journey Builder's Decision Split

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm having a bit of an issue with Journey Builder's Decision Split; it keeps routing contacts to the incorrect path. Wondering if you could help?

I have an JB entry source DE "Entry DE" and a "Master DE". They both have the same PrimaryKey and are connected 1:1 on Primary Key. Master DE's PrimaryKey is linked to Contact Key on Contacts.

"Master DE" has a field called "Member No", and the decision split is based on this "Member No" field. JB keeps thinking all contacts have "Member No" even though only half of them do. Any tips what to check to resolve the issue?

TIA

@Eliot:
 [image]

Comment: try adding the wait time before the decision slip once and check it.

Comment: please can you share a screenshot of the contact filter criteria used in your Decision Split Activity?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra Same outcome even with the added wait times

Comment: @EliotHarper Is the attached what you were after? It's a contact data > Master DE > Member No filter. I tried swapping it as well to Member No isnull but same results.

Comment: Odd, I can't think of any logical reason why this would not work. If you don't have any other responses to your question, I'd be happy to jump on a quick webinar and review your configuration with you, as it's hard to debug over a comment thread. You can contact me at eliot.harper[at]salesforcemvps.com

Comment: Can you confirm that `Member_Number` is **not used** as a cardinal relationship in your Contact Model (within an Attribute Group)? If it is, then the behavior that you are experiencing would be expected; all Contacts without a Member Number would be routed through the first branch.

Comment: Hi @EliotHarper, I don't think so. Only Subcriber Key/Primary Key are being used to build relationships? Can you please explain further?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check to see if the value of Member No is actually "NULL".  I've noticed that empty fields are not always NULL.